# Extbase UriBuilder and RealUrl on Ajax Requests

Tags: vue.js, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I'm developing a TYPO3 plugin, which outputs a list of records in VueJS. 
Therefor I created a controller action which returns requested records as json.

Every record has a property "uri", which holds the uri to its detail page. I generate this uri with the Extbase uriBuilder.

The first records are loaded directly within my list action, where I assign this set of records to the VueJs application directly in the frontend (v-bind:items="my_json_objects").

The next set of records will be loaded on demand by calling my API which returns the same type of records.

Problem: The uri built by uriBuilder returns a rewritten url only in the first case, when objects assigned directly to VueJS. For all items loaded by ajax calls, uribuilder returns the non-rewritten url.

Both actions calls the same method to build the uri:

```
$item['uri'] = $this->buildShowUri($item);
```

The method to build the uri:

```
return $this->uriBuilder
        ->reset()
        ->setTargetPageUid(56) // currently static, for testing
        ->setCreateAbsoluteUri(true)
        ->uriFor(
            'show',
            [
                'item' => $item,
            ]
        );
```

Is there a way to trigger url rewriting in this way? Do I need to register the uri somewhere to realurl?

Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: May be you have to add more infos (Controller, Extension, Plugin etc) than just the action name to the uriFor method.

Answer (score 2):

How stupid. The uribuilder works, but I forgot to enable realurl in the page type which delivers the json output.

```
json = PAGE
json {
config {
    linkVars = L(0-4)
    **tx_realurl_enable = 1**
    sys_language_mode = strict
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    debug = 0
    no_cache = 1
    additionalHeaders {
        10 {
            header = Content-Type: application/json
            replace = 1
        }
    }
}
typeNum = 129912

10 = USER
10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = MyExt
    pluginName = Plug
    vendorName = Myself
    controller = Events
    action = apiList
    switchableControllerActions {
        Event {
            1 = apiList
        }
    }
}
```

}